# How to remove "Toggling multi-web-mode off; better pass an explicit argument" message in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, mode

I have noticed, from a while, that every time I run emacs in [multi-web-mode](https://github.com/fgallina/multi-web-mode) I get the following message:"**Toggling multi-web-mode off; better pass an explicit argument**".

Why do I get that? multi-web-mode is not toggled off because I use it and it works fine, but I keep getting this message all the time.

How can I fix this little trouble?

This is my code in my .emacs file where "multi-web-mode" appears (I am using Emacs 23.4):

```el
(require 'multi-web-mode)
(setq mweb-default-major-mode 'html-mode)
(setq mweb-tags '((c++-mode "<\\?php\\|<\\? \\|<\\?=" "\\?>")
                  (ecmascript-mode "<script +\\(type=\"text/javascript\"\\|language=\"javascript\"\\)[^>]*>" "</script>")
                  (css-mode "<style +type=\"text/css\"[^>]*>" "</style>")))
(setq mweb-filename-extensions '("php" "htm" "html" "ctp" "phtml" "php4" "php5"))
(multi-web-global-mode 1)

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php\\'" . multi-web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html\\'" . multi-web-mode))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it sounds like somewhere there's some code causing this mode to be called, non-interactively, with no arguments: `(multi-web-mode)`. A common cause would be specifying a mode function symbol for use as a callback, rather than specifying a function which will *call* that mode function (with an argument).

This certainly used to be bad form, as it would indeed act as a toggle, just as it does in the interactive case (e.g. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `multi-web-mode`). Since Emacs 24, however, it is actually safe to do (at least for modes defined with the standard macros), as a non-interactive call with no argument to a mode function now always means 'enable'. This might account for the fact that you're not actually seeing a problem.

<del>I don't think stock Emacs has ever generated such a message, so I would presume it's multi-web-mode itself which is detecting and reporting on this. It may need to be updated to reflect the change in Emacs 24.</del> (*Edit:* looks like I was wrong about that; I guess Emacs 23.4 did produce this warning.)

Your simplest fix is probably to show us any lines from your config which mention `multi-web-mode`, so someone can show you how to change it to ensure that it passes an explicit argument (which is typically `1` to enable a mode).

---

*Edit:* Okay, your problem is that `multi-web-mode` is a minor mode (as opposed to a major mode), but you have specified it in `auto-mode-alist` which is a mechanism for mapping filename patterns to *major* modes.

So the cause is exactly as I suggested above when I said "A common cause would be specifying a mode function symbol for use as a callback", as those auto-mode-alist entries will result in a call to `(multi-web-mode)`.

It appears to me that `multi-web-global-mode` handles enabling the minor mode as required, so you just need to remove the bad `auto-mode-alist` entries.

Comment: You are suggesting me to delete this two lines from my .emacs, right?
`(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php\\'" . multi-web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html\\'" . multi-web-mode))`

How can I open .php and .html files with multi-web-mode then?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm suggesting. It's not a major mode, so it never made any sense to have those entries. Your *previous* two lines ensure that all of the following file extensions utilise multi-web-mode: ("php" "htm" "html" "ctp" "phtml" "php4" "php5"). I don't know if it even matters which major mode those buffers start in, but if you do need auto-mode-alist entries for them, you *must* specify a major mode, not a minor mode.

Comment: I will add that the documentation indicates the purpose of multi-web-mode is just to to *switch between* major modes when editing, so you'll certainly need a major mode for PHP, as Emacs doesn't have one by default. If you don't have a `php-mode` already, I would recommend using this one: https://github.com/ejmr/php-mode